# How to play with devices like accelerometer and camera using C/C++?

Tags: android, architecture, android-sensors

As you can see in architecture diagram below android platform has been built using different layers.

- `Application` are developed in `Java`
- `Application Framework` is written using `Java` (according to my understanding)
- `Libraries` are in `C/C++`

[image]

For some insane reason I have to play/deal with devices like `accelerometer`, `compass` and `camera` using `C/C++` which means directly accessing them in 3rd layer i.e. `Libraries`. According to my understanding the `Application Framework` itself would be consuming `Libraries` for accessing these devices and then providing `APIs` for `Applications`.

I am looking for any  documentation/tutorials/demo which can help me in this regard i.e how to access and use these devices like camera, accelerometer and compass from `C/C++` code or in other words how to play with these devices directly from `Libraries` layer.

My last option would be to get the android source code and dig deep into it to find out what I am looking for but I would like some easy way in form of a documentation/demo/tutorial/anything that can make this a bit easy for me.

Comment: I'm not an android dev per say but trailing the related questions seem to provide pointers as to how you maybe able to do this

Comment: @Haris: did you eventually manage to access camera using C?

Comment: Nope, I used Java APIs instead because it is not recommended to use low level APIs by Google due to the fact that they can be changed any time.

Comment: This is possible using the android NDK, is it still relevant to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am looking for any documentation/tutorials/demo which can help me in this regard i.e how to access and use these devices like camera, accelerometer and compass from C/C++ code or in other words how to play with these devices directly from Libraries layer.

You don't. You access them from Java code. Reorganize your C/C++ code to support your Java code.

Answer (score 1):

For the camera, you can use opencv to access the frames with a c++ library. For the Accelerometer, I'm looking for how to access using c++.