# Should I never use native (C/C++) libraries for interacting with devices?

Tags: android

Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491857/how-to-play-with-devices-like-accelerometer-and-camera-using-c-c) question for a bit of background of what I am trying to achieve. While looking on internet for the answer I found [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-framework@googlegroups.com/msg00934.html) thread. In this thread a Google's employee says this about using native (C/C++) libraries for accessing camera

```
You CANNOT do that. Please, understand that Native APIS ARE NOT PUBLIC
(sorry for shouting).
All these APIS may/will go away or change in ways that will make your
application *crash* in the near future.
We are not, and will not, try to maintain binary compatibility on native APIs.

You *can* use native code if you wish, but you ABSOLUTELY CANNOT call
into Android native APIs. That's a no-no. And you won't find help from
the Android team here about this subject.
```

My question: does this mean one should never try to deal with any devices like accelerometer, camera, compass, etc using native libraries in any case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just as he wrote, those APIs are internal, and might change between versions and models. Each vendor may change ANYTHING there, and soon enough your application will cease to function on many devices.

Comment: My understanding was that these native Libraries, which lies in 'Libraries' section of android architecture, won't have to do anything with specific vendor. I thought that these are generic libraries which Application Framework consumes. Isn't it the case?

Comment: Application framework consumes those so you will not use them, and to provide you an interface, even if a specific vendor won't change those (and I think they will many time), it might be changed in the next version of android.